# What does firebase expect to find in my osx keychain?

Tags: ios, firebase, keychain

I'm currently getting an error on firebase init.

```
2019-05-03 15:55:24.945218-0500 ChooseHealthApp[5538:1534233] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] Info is not found in Keychain. OSStatus: -25300. Keychain query: {
    acct = "com.myAppName.foo";
    class = genp;
    gena = "com.google.iid";
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    "r_Data" = 1;
    svce = "com.google.iid.checkin";
}
2019-05-03 15:55:24.945697-0500 ChooseHealthApp[5538:1534233] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] Info is not found in Keychain. OSStatus: -25300. Keychain query: {
    atag = <636f6d2e 676f6f67 6c652e69 69642d7c 4b7c>;
    class = keys;
    "r_Ref" = 1;
    type = 42;
}
2019-05-03 15:55:24.945894-0500 ChooseHealthApp[5538:1534233] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] Info is not found in Keychain. OSStatus: -25300. Keychain query: {
    atag = <636f6d2e 676f6f67 6c652e69 69642d7c 507c>;
    class = keys;
    "r_Ref" = 1;
    type = 42;
}
2019-05-03 15:55:24.945984-0500 ChooseHealthApp[5538:1534233] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009000] No keypair info is found with tag com.google.iid-|K|
```

I'm using [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) which (almost certainly) uses [firebase-ios-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk).

What I don't understand about the error above is what firebase was expecting to be there.  At no point in any of the docs I've read have I seen mention of adding an item to the keychain.  The closest thing I've found is this (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs#create_the_authentication_key) and it makes no mention of keychain or `com.google.iid`.

I've searched for any link between firebase and keychain and found nothing.

What's going on here?  What interaction is firebase expecting to have with keychain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also asked this question on github issues:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2438#issuecomment-489239459

The response was:

> This is just info log showing you don't have legacy keychain.

In my case, I ended up finding another less verbose error which was the root of the problem.